# not able to call "uploadProgress" in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 $.ajax({

            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/something/somthing",         
            data: oMyForm,              
            type: "POST",               
            processData: false,            
            contentType: false,

         beforeSend: function () {       
                alert("beforeSend");                
                status.empty();
                var percentVal = '0%';
                bar.width(percentVal);
                percent.html(percentVal);

            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {            
                alert("uploadProgress");                
                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                bar.width(percentVal);
                percent.html(percentVal);

            },
            success: function () {              
                alert("success");               
                var percentVal = '100%';
                bar.width(percentVal);
                percent.html(percentVal);

            },
            complete: function (xhr) {              
                alert("xhr:" +xhr);             
                alert("complete");              
                status.html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Here i am able to get a file from the controller and i put alert inside uploadprogress but its not coming. Can you please anyone solve this issue?

Advance in Thanks

Comment: What in the world is `uploadProgress`? I don't see it anywhere in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Okay understood. i've just used "<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> " blugin